# Open another emacs and cause conflicts

Tags: process, desktop

I have a GUI emacs running as the major working area,

When I reading articles from web, need to open a emacs  as a tool to keep note;

Web on the left and new emacs on the right,

Usually, get the prompts

```
Please answer y or n.  Warning: desktop file appears to be in use by PID 17861.                                               
Using it may cause conflicts.  Use it anyway? (y or n)
```

I assure the conflicts are the buffer.

Should I ignore it to continue or actions could be taken to tackle the prompt?

Comment: Are you using `desktop-save-mode`?

Comment: Two questions: 1) What happens if you answer `n` to the prompt? 2) Would opening a new frame instead with key chords `C-x` `5` `2` help? BTW the `C` in `C-x` is `Cntrl` key so `C-x` means press `Control` and `x`  keys and same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't usefully have two simultaneous Emacs session that use the same file to store the session state. Each time a session saves its state, it would overwrite the other session's state.

Many people run a single Emacs session. To open a file in the existing Emacs session, use [`emacsclient`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html) (see also [the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient)). Emacsclient has several options to control its behavior, including whether to open a new window (`-c`) or run inside the current terminal (`-t`) or let you switch to the existing window (default). Emacsclient can start Emacs if needed (`emacsclien --alternate-editor=`).

I normally start Emacs when I log in, and I use Desktop to save my session. In order to be able to occasionally run a separate instance of Emacs, I arrange to only use Desktop if Emacs is invoked in a special way, and I invoke Emacs in this special way in my operating system's session startup. Specifically, I run this when I log in:

```sh
EMACS_SESSION_DIR=~/.emacs.d/session emacs --daemon
```

This runs `emacs --daemon` (so it doesn't open any Emacs window) and loads my normal session which is stored in the directory `~/.emacs.d/session`. Here's the code from my Emacs init file to only use Desktop if `EMACS_SESSION_DIR` is set.

```elisp
(let ((env (getenv "EMACS_SESSION_DIR")))
  (unless (or (null env) (equal env ""))
    (setq desktop-dirname (expand-file-name env)
          desktop-path (list desktop-dirname))))

;; `desktop' will look for `desktop-basefilename' in the current directory,
;; then in the home directory. But I don't ordinarily want that.
(defadvice desktop-read
  (around dont-search-state-file-in-current-directory activate)
  "Don't let Desktop look for the state file in the current directory."
  (let ((default-directory desktop-dirname))
    ad-do-it))

;; Enable desktop if a session directory has been defined.
(setq desktop-enable (and desktop-dirname t))
```

(Some of this code was writen a long time ago and may no longer be necessary in modern Emacs versions.)